# Where to order custom mini-figs in Europe

Tags: minifigures, star-wars, customization

General question is are there any custom Lego minifig online stores in Europe like there are many in the US ?

In detail:
My friends friend is getting married and she would like to surprise them with an original gift.
She is looking for two specific LEGO minifigs, custom or not but from sellers in Europe because she needs those for next Wednesday. these are the minifigs she is looking for:

Star Wars Queen Amidala 
http://www.ebay.com/itm/LEGO-Custom-Star-Wars-Queen-Amidala-4-Handmaidens-Invasion-Dress-03dB-/170787423998?pt=Building_Toys_US&hash=item27c3b946fe

Mario
http://images.sodahead.com/polls/001480721/3cea492bc51cc7ffd403f2deaf7cb328_answer_5_xlarge.jpeg

They don't have to be these exact ones but those same characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your friend can get Queen Amidala at several shops based in Europe. Here are all the listings with the country of the shop: http://www.bricklink.com/catalogPG.asp?M=sw387. It might be also worth checking the eBay listings specific for their country.

As far as Mario, LEGO never made an official one, however this UK based store does carry some: http://www.customminifig.co.uk/super-mario-bro-custom-minifig/

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions they are quite helpful. I searched on Bricklink and found some of these stores but this format of search results is much easer to read (how did you get it in this format). This store in the UK does seem promising and I am going to send her the link. I visited it earlier once but didn't know they are UK based (it's obvious of course but it wasn't relevant to me back then). Are there any other stores in Europe that you know of? Some preferably in Austria or Germany.

Comment: To answer your first question, my preferred method of searching on BrickLink is to use Catalog Items, instead of Items for Sale search. For example in the case of Amidala, I would type Amidala in the search box at the top of the BrickLink front page, but switch the drop-down menu next to it from Items for Sale to Catalog Items. The search will give me the results. Then I click on the one I want (in this case the Amidala Minifigure). Under the item details there will be a link to the rigth titled Price Guide info. If you click on that, you will get the sceen you were looking for.

Comment: In regard to your second question, there are many-many stores in Europe. On this page you can see all of them categorized by country: http://www.bricklink.com/browse.asp