# Where can I go to get good custom LEGO minifigures?

Tags: minifigures, shopping, customization

I want certain LEGO minifigures, but TLG doesn't make them. I would like to find someone or someplace to get some good custom minifigures. I can pay.

Comment: Some of the answers in http://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/4278/where-to-order-custom-mini-figs-in-europe may apply here.

Answer (score 1):

There are several minifig-customizer businesses ... the most famous one is likely http://minifigs.me.